# MySQL schema design issues - Normalizing

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema, rdbms

I'm creating tables for my site using the following design(s)

**Design 1**

[image]

**Design 2**

[image]

Since not every user who register will try the challenge, **Design 1** is suited. On insert into third table, table 2 score is updated accordingly. But the user_id field becomes redundant.

Either 0 or NULL values are set for every user in design 2 which still isn't normalized.
What would be the optimal design and how important is normalization or key in an organization?

Comment: does each row in the pictures represent a different table?  do they have names?  can you explain some more about what the challenges are and how they're represented in the pictures at all?

Comment: so... you need a `user` table?  and then a `challenge` table...?  and users can take multiple challenges, and challenges can be done by different users?  and you want to record the scores?  is that correct?  can you explain what's going on a little but more?

Comment: Yes you're right. They do have table name. Users, challenge,scores accordingly. Its basically like stackoverflow reputation. Since its displayed on every page, i need to store the overall score user has earned over different challenge. But a user might not take up the challenge and the score remains zero and is still dislayed

Comment: okay.... look at the answer I pasted below and tell me if that works for you.  I still don't understand part of what you're saying... or why "_since its displayed on every page, i need to store the overall score user has earned over different challenge. But a user might not take up the challenge and the score remains zero and is still dislayed_" has anything to do with schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:

For future people - I had some problems understanding what OP was asking for so read through the comments if you get  a little lost.  Ultimately, they were looking to store aggregate data and didn't know where to put it or how to make it happen.  The solution is basically to use an *insert trigger*, which is explained near the end of this post.

I chose to just add another column on to the `user` table to store the accumulated sum of `user_problem.score`.  However, making a new table (with the columns `user_id` and `total_sum`) isn't a bad option at all even though it seems to be an excessive use of normalization.  Sometimes it is good to keep data that is constantly updated separate from data that is rarely changed.  That way if something goes wrong, you know your static data will be safe.

Something else I never touched on are the *data concurrency* and *integrity* issues associated with storing aggregate data in general... so beware of that.

---

I would suggest something like this:

```
User Table
User_ID  -  Email  -  Name  -  Password  -  FB_ID 
-- holds all the user information 


Problem Table
Problem_ID  -  Problem_Title  -  Problem_Descr 
-- holds all the info on the individual challenges/problems/whatever


User_Problem Table
User_Problem_ID  -  User_ID  -  Problem_ID  -  Score  -  Completion_Date
-- Joins the User and Problem tables and has information specific
-- to a user+challenge pair
```

And this assumes that a user can take many challenges/problems.  And one problem/challenge can be taken by several users.

To see all the problems by a certain user, you would do something like:

```
select  user.user_id, 
        user.name,
        problem_title, 
        problem_descr, 
        user_problem.score, 
        user_problem.completed_date

from    user 

        join user_problem on user.user_id = user_problem.user_id 

        join problem on user_problem.problem_id = problem.problem_id 

where   user.user_id = 123 or user.email = 'stuff@gmail.com'
```

The lengths for the `varchar` fields are fairly generic...

```
create table User(
  User_ID   int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
  Email     varchar(100), 
  Name      varchar(100), 
  Password  varchar(100), 
  FB_ID     int
); 

create table Problem (
  Problem_ID    int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
  Problem_Title varchar(100), 
  Problem_Descr varchar(500)
); 

create table User_Problem (
  User_Problem_ID int unsigned auto_increment primary key, 
  User_ID         int unsigned,
  Problem_ID      int unsigned, 
  Score           int,
  Completion_Date datetime,

  foreign key (User_ID) references User (User_ID), 
  foreign key (Problem_ID) references Problem (Problem_ID)
);
```

---

After our conversation from down below in the comments... you would add a column to user:

```
User Table
User_ID  -  Email  -  Name  -  Password  -  FB_ID  -  Total_Score
```

I gave the column a default value of 0 because you seemed to want/need that if the person didn't have any associated problem/challenges.  Depending on other things, it may benefit you to make this an `unsigned` int if you have a rule which states there will never be a negative score.

```
alter table user add column Total_Score int default 0;
```

then... you would use an insert trigger on the `user_problem` table that affects the `user` table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_update_total_score 

AFTER INSERT ON User_Problem 
FOR EACH ROW

  UPDATE User
     SET Total_score = Total_score + New.Score
   WHERE User_ID = NEW.User_ID;
```

So... after a row is added to `User_Problem`, you would add the new score to `user.total_score`...

```
mysql> select * from user;
+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+-------------+
| User_ID | Email | Name | Password | FB_ID | Total_Score |
+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+-------------+
|       1 | NULL  | kim  | NULL     |  NULL |           0 |
|       2 | NULL  | kyle | NULL     |  NULL |           0 |
+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into user_problem values (null,1,1,10,now());
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> select * from user;
+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+-------------+
| User_ID | Email | Name | Password | FB_ID | Total_Score |
+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+-------------+
|       1 | NULL  | kim  | NULL     |  NULL |          10 |
|       2 | NULL  | kyle | NULL     |  NULL |           0 |
+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from user_problem;
+-----------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------------+
| User_Problem_ID | User_ID | Problem_ID | Score | Completion_Date     |
+-----------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------------+
|               1 |       1 |          1 |    10 | 2013-11-03 11:31:53 |
+-----------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: But according to the above design, assuming a user has taken up many challenges, overall score has to computed everytime

Comment: okay... I'm not sure I'm following you.  You could have a table (or field in user) that stores the calculated score values...?  And use an insert trigger so whenever a row is added to `user_problem`, it would update the total score (where ever you decided to place it).

Comment: Okay what i meant is suppose a user **A** completes 10 challenges and 10 credits are allotted for each challenge. So his overall score would be 100. But 100 isn't stored directly. Credits obtained for each challenge is summed up and displayed each time we query for a score

Comment: Right... so you just want to store the aggregate total/data somewhere so it's faster to access?  is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, having a field in user table works as specified in design 2 but there could be possibility that not many users will take up a challenge and the score field has to be set to 0 for each user

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for your extensive help. I'm trying to implement the most optimal design. This works!